# What is the best way to compare a name field with a string value?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

I have a query that compares a string value against a name field in my database. The structure of the name field in the DB is not consistent, it could be any of these:

```
John Doe
Doe John
Doe, John
```

My string value can be in any structure, but right now it is like so:

```
Doe, John
```

Query:

```
full_name ILIKE 'Doe, John%'
```

This doesn't always return records. What is the most reliable query to make a comparison in any structure?

Comment: `full_name in ('John Doe', 'Doe John', 'Doe, John')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** - as commented by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) : the `IN` condition

```
full_name IN ('John Doe', 'Doe John', 'Doe, John')
```

If you  know in advance all the possible variations of the full name, this is the most efficient approach. With an index on column `full_name`, that should be very fast.

**Option 2** : ensure that both first and last name are part of the string :

```
full_name LIKE '%John%' AND full_name LIKE '%Doe%'
```

This is really less efficient. Using `LIKE` with a wildcard on the left basically defeats an index on column `full_name`, and generates a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
replace(replace(trim(full_name), ' ', ', '), ',,', ',')
```

will transform full_name to:

`'John, Doe'` or `'Doe, John'`
even if it does not contain `,`. 
These:

```
left(pattern, strpos(pattern, ',') - 1)
trim(substring(pattern, strpos(pattern, ',') + 1))
```

extract what is left and right of `,` in your pattern string value. 
So you can do this:

```
replace(replace(trim(full_name), ' ', ', '), ',,', ',') in ( 
  pattern,
  concat(
    trim(substring(pattern, strpos(pattern, ',') + 1)),
    ', ',
    left(pattern, strpos(pattern, ',') - 1)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split this into names and then compare using `like`.  For instance:

```
where (select bool_and('doe john' like '%' || name || '%')
        from unnest(string_to_array(v.str, ' ')) name
       )
```

The `bool_and()` requires that all components match.

That said, you should fix the data model, so you store first and last names in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this

```
full_name like any (values ('%John%', '%Doe%'))
```